# Request to ASMX service with WS-Addressing

Tags: c#, asmx, ws-addressing

We have an **ASMX** web-service. I know, it's obsolete, but we have to keep it. So, I have a client-application that sends request (with **WS-Addressing** headers) to the method of this service:

```
someASMX.someSoapClient client = new someASMX.someSoapClient();
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.ReplyTo = new EndpointAddress("https://address2answer");
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.MessageId = new System.Xml.UniqueId(Guid.NewGuid());
    client.someMethod("1", "test");
}
```

But request fails with the following exception:

`Addressing Version 'AddressingNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)' does not support adding WS-Addressing headers`

Does ASMX web-services even support WS-Addressing then? If they do, what should I do to make it accept requests with WS-Addressing headers?

I have the following binding in `app.config` of the client:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="someSoap">
    <security mode="Transport" />
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

<endpoint address="https://someserver:443/some.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="someSoap"
    contract="someNS.someSoap" name="someSoap" />
```

I suspect it has to do something with bindings, but that's auto-generated stuff from adding `Service Reference` in Visual Studio - why it was generated that way then? Maybe I need to change something on the ASMX service's side?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I haven't done enough research about ASMX - it does not support **wsHttpBinding**. So we should get rid of it and create a WCF-service with wsHttpBinding endpoint.